# Product Name from GS128 Barcode / GTIN

Tags: barcode, barcode-scanner, decoder, code128, gs1-datamatrix

I have GS128 barcode and my scanner scans the GTIN value of it. I want to get the product name from the GTIN value without referring any database. The exact requirement is in my store, I have a new product whose data is not available in the database. On scanning the product which as GS128 barcode , I want to get/retrieve the product name from the barcode. Is there any way I can get product name directly from barcode without having a look on the database.

Comment: Barcodes don't generally encode any textual data, only the numeric identifier of the product. You can't get out something that isn't there.

Comment: The number encoded is designed to be referenced from a data store of some kind. There is no extra information in the code, but the number reported by the scanner, the stop and start codes and the checksum. The only way to get a product name out of a barcode is to put it there, but then it would not be a Global Trade Item Number.

Answer (score 1):

GTIN is the [Global Trade Number](https://www.gs1.org/standards/id-keys/gtin).  So it does not directly describe the product name in a text format.

You can use that number to know the country which is in the [prefix](https://www.gs1.org/standards/id-keys/company-prefix).

If you are not concerned about GTIN, you could use another barcode format, such as code 128, QR or PDF 417 and use a custom format that includes the product name in that barcode.